# How to have searchlogic initialize with no records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, searchlogic

I'm using [Searchlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic) in a model with tens of thousands of records and don't want to initially display them all the first time the search page loads. How do I get an empty search object from searchlogic if there are no :search params?

```
  def search
    @products = []
    if params[:search] && !params[:search].blank?
      @search = Product.searchlogic(params[:search])
    else
      @search = Product.searchlogic(....What goes here to get an empty searchlogic object?...)
    end
    @products = @search.all
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your logic to this:

```
def search
    @products = []
    @search = params[:search] && !params[:search].blank? ?
        Product.searchlogic(params[:search]) : nil
    @products = @search.all unless @search.nil?
end
```

Granted you could keep your if statement like so:

```
def search
    @products = []
    @search = nil
    if params[:search] && !params[:search].blank?
        Product.searchlogic(params[:search])
    end
    @products = @search.all unless @search.nil?
end
```